# Recognize datalist selection vs. text input in BootstrapVue Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

Having the following sample code, I want to know the proper event/method to distinguish if the value filled in the input was entered manually or selected from the `<datalist>`.

TEMPLATE:

```
<div>
    <b-form-input list="my-list-id"
        v-on:change="handleChange" v-model="sizeSel"/>
    <datalist id="my-list-id">
        <option v-for="size in sizes">{{ size }}</option>
    </datalist>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
{
  data() {
    return {
      sizeSel: '',
      sizes: ['Small', 'Medium', 'Large', 'Extra Large']
    }
  },
  watch: {    
  },
  methods: {
    handleChange() {
      alert(this.sizeSel);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use `keydown`

`<datalist>` doesn't have its own events but this can be done anyway.

Both keyboard events and `<datalist>` clicks trigger the input's `keydown` listener, but only keyboard events have a `key` property.  So if a `keydown` is triggered having no `key` property, you know it was a click from the list:

Try this:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      sizes: ['Small', 'Medium', 'Large', 'Extra Large'],
      sizeSel: '',
      sizeChangedBy: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onkeydown(e) {
      const eventSource = e.key ? 'input' : 'list';
      this.sizeChangedBy = eventSource;
    }
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    Event source: {{ sizeChangedBy }}<br />
    <label for="myInput">Choose one:</label>
    <input list="sizes" id="myInput" name="myInput" v-model="sizeSel" @keydown="onkeydown($event)" />
    <datalist id="sizes">
      <option v-for="size in sizes" :key="size" :value="size"></option>
    </datalist>
  </div>
</div>
```